# remote mongo authentication issue using mongoose on a node app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

trying to get node-passport-mongoose to connect to remote mongodb using authentication.

**The node app connection works fine when remote mongodb auth is turned off using:**

module.exports = {
    'url' : 'mongodb://pubip:27017/test'
};

**With remote mongo auth turned on - I can then successfully login from the local shell with:**

mongo pubip:27017/test -u dave -p password

**but if I then update my database.js config in my node app to this:**

module.exports = {
    'url' : 'mongodb://dave:password@pubip:27017/test'
};

**I get this:**

*/home/ubuntu/semblent/passport/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^
Error
    at Error.MongoError (/home/ubuntu/semblent/passport/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:13:17)
    at Server.destroy (/home/ubuntu/semblent/passport/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:629:47)
    at Server.close (/home/ubuntu/semblent/passport/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:344:17)
    at Db.close (/home/ubuntu/semblent/passport/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:267:19)
    at /home/ubuntu/semblent/passport/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:196:12
    at null. (/home/ubuntu/semblent/passport/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:226:9)
    at g (events.js:180:16)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at null. (/home/ubuntu/semblent/passport/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:238:68)
    at g (events.js:180:16)*

**Any tips appreciated !!**

Comment: What mongo shell version are you using? What MongoDB version? What version of mongoose?

Comment: Hi - running db.version() inside the mongo shell on the remote server I get 3.0.1. Looking at my package.json I see Im using "mongoose": "~4.0.1" and my local mongo shell locally version is also 3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad...
seems I had not set up my user definition correctly - this one works:

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "benny",
      pwd: "butter",
      roles: [
         { "role" : "dbAdmin", db: "test" },
         { "role" : "userAdmin", db: "test"},
         { "role" : "readWrite", "db" : "test" }
      ]
    }
)
```

I was missing the readWrite role before - I had mistakenly assumed you would get that with either the dbAdmin or userAdmin roles.